# Drush failing on preflight: A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value

Tags: 8, drush

I can't run drush in my current project. The error I keep getting is:

> [preflight] A colon cannot be used in an unquoted mapping value at line 3 (near " in Command line code on line 1").

This is a Drupal 8 project I've recently updated and I'm about to migrate to Drupal 9. I'm running Drush 10.3.1
I've deleted and reinstalled drush, `/vendor`, and `/core`.

I'm guessing "Command" should point me to something but I can't figure out what.
Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What command are you running? Does it have a YAML string in it?

Comment: Any drush command

drush
drush cr
drush updb

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: PHP version 7.4.13